# How to insert a table in table in html with few columns merged

Tags: html, css, angularjs, html-table

My html table has few applications from university groups.

Each university can have different groups. Each group has only one student for now.

I have html with angular code something like this

```
    <table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>State</th>
      <th>Group Name</th>
      <th>University</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="application in $ctrl.applications track by application.id"
      <td>
        <div ng-repeat="student in ::application.students track by $index">
          {{:: student.name }}
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div ng-repeat="student in ::application.students track by $index">
          {{:: student.address }}
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div ng-repeat="student in ::application.students track by $index">
          {{:: customer.state }}
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>{{:: application.groupName}}</td>
      <td>{{:: application.university }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This gives me current output as

[image]

Now there is a change of requirement.

Each group can have any number of students. Each student has his/her own Address, State.

Now the table should look something like this

[image]

However, if I pass the modified data (where there are multiple students in single application), I see this

[image]

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Edit:

Missed to mention one thing before.

The whole row is clickable.

So, in the second image (which is the desired output), I should be able to click on Alex and Steve at the same time i.e, they should treated as single cell in table.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `rowspan`:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_rowspan.asp

This way you can merge cells. Look at `colspan` as well, for columns.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. However, I see a challenge here. 1. Alex and Steve should be treated as single row so that the row can be clicked. I added this in the edit section of post. I cannot treat every student as a row. In my case, every application is a row. I am little bit confused about using rowspan here.

Comment: My suggestion was so that you do not need to insert table-in-table nesting.. If you however want to be able to click a cell/row in that table (not sure how you click those), you could stick to your THIRD picture..  But then you are saying that "there are multiple students in single application" .. so you either have the 2 students in their own rows (and click them individually) or have them combined in a single row (and single-click them) ... so I am not sure what your end goal is?

Comment: Another option would be to use checkboxes in front of these rows, so you select both Alex and Steve, and then perform some action.